# decode json from another file php

Tags: php, json

I have some promblem, I create php file (json_code.php) and wrote php code to create JSON output. Here the code :

```
require_once('connect.php');
require_once('studentdb.php');

$query = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM student");
$query->execute();
while($data = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
    $temp_student = new StudentDB($data['id'], $data['name'], $data['address'], $data['age']);
    $student_array[] = $temp_student;
}

header("Content-Type: application/json");
$dale_data = json_encode($student_array[0]);

echo '{"student":[';
echo $dale_data;
echo ']}';
```

That JSON output showed like this:

```
{"student":[{"id":"1","name":"Ghale","address":"Street abcdfgh","age":"22"}]}
```

I want to read that JSON with another file php, then I create file read_json.php, the code like this :

```
$json_url = 'http://localhost/test1/json_code.php';
$ch = curl_init( $json_url );
$json_string = array();
$options = array(
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
    CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array('Content-type: application/json') ,
    CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => $json_string
);
curl_setopt_array( $ch, $options ); // Setting curl options
echo $result =  curl_exec($ch); // Getting jSON result string
$decode = json_decode($result, true);
print_r($decode);
```

But it's did not show anything :(
How to read that JSON output from another file php? Please help :( Sorry for bad english

Comment: check is curl enabled?

Comment: you don't need curl, try `echo json_decode(file_get_contents('http://localhost/test1/json_code.php'))`

Comment: your code is 100% fine, i have test with the same example, check is your curl enabled or just test with a simple array instead of query..

Comment: If you stuck with json_decode use $error = json_last_error(); to see whats going wrong.

Comment: devpro : curl already enable but still did not work :(.
Clayton : I try your code but it show me this file_get_contents(http://localhost/test1/json_code.php): failed to open stream: No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it :(.

Comment: allright, just use this testing array and comment your query and connection,  $array = array('test'=>1);
  $data = json_encode($array);

  echo '{"student":[';
  echo $data;
  echo ']}';

Comment: Sounds like a configuration problem on your machine.  If you go to the URL `http://localhost/test1/json_code.php` in your browser does it load?

Comment: Is your server running on port 80?

Comment: http://localhost:82/test1/json_code.php, i use port 82 if want to load that file with browser.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it will be easier and less confusing if you use file_get_contents to get your JSON.  Try this:

```
echo json_decode(file_get_contents('http://localhost:82/test1/json_code.php'));
```

If you just want to examine the output of your json_code.php file do this:

```
echo file_get_contents('http://localhost:82/test1/json_code.php');
```

Comment: I use port in localhost, 'localhost:82/test1/json_code.php' to open that file in browser. is that make a problem?

Comment: it show, file_get_contents(http://localhost/test1/json_code.php): failed to open stream: No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it

Comment: if you do not specify a port number it defaults to 80 which explains why it wasn't working.

Comment: hey it work! i use echo json_decode(file_get_contents('http://localhost:82/test1/json_code.php'));. I miss that port. Thankyou so much all !